# Two touchscreen for Ubuntu and mapping of touch events

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, xrandr, xinput, touch-screen

i've a touchscreen laptop (1920x1080) and a ineractive whiteboard with touch (1280x800). 
To use the full resolution of the laptop i just present a part of the monitor, that is done succesfully with the first xrandr command.

Now i want to map the touch events of the monitor to the laptop monitor, which works.
Because the whiteboard has always different number by `xinput list` i grep the number and show it on the bash. Then i map the touch events of the whiteboard to this part of the presented screen.

The last commands are a part of xfce4 to maximise any window inside the presented part of my laptop screen.

`#!/bin/
sh xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off --output eDP1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI1 --mode 1280x800 --pos 480x270 --rotate normal 
xinput map-to-output 'ELAN Touchscreen' eDP1 
daten=$(xinput list | grep 'TimeLink' | tail -n 1 | cut -c 56-57) 
echo $daten 
xinput map-to-output "$daten" HDMI1 
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/margin_right -s 160 
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/margin_left -s 480 
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/margin_top -s 270 
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/margin_bottom -s 10`

This script worked fine, but suddenly the mapping of the whiteboard didn't function any more. At the left and right margin there get a displace of the mouse position and the touch event. I tried to calibrate the monitor by deactivating eDP1 and use `xinput_calibrator` for the whiteboard and wrote this into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf` like the programme suggested.
But the touch event is after a reboot still perfect in the middle but gets worse on both margin, left and right.

I also checked, if any programme was updated, but i found nothing helpful.
The beamer also just show the picture without any new ratio and so on.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found a solution.

Setting "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" failed, but setting libinput Claibration Matrix suceeded.

```
xinput set-prop  DEVICE "libinput Calibration Matrix" 1.100000, 0.000000, -0.050000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

DEVICE need to be substitued by the number from *xinput list*

The values are found by trial&error, but this 2 Numbers are for the x_width and x_offset.